# Do we need to notarize frameworks(.framework), dylibs and binaries?

Tags: macos, code-signing, macos-mojave, notarize, stapler

Reading the apple docs about notarization it is not clear if we need to notarize binaries(for example a launch daemon), frameworks or dylibs.

Do we need to also notarize these?

The apple docs can be found here [Notarizing Your App Before Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question here, maybe it helps someone.

This can be done automatically by Xcode; however if you need to manually configure this(maybe you have Continuous Integration, or w/e) this might help.

### According to Apple:

> Notarization gives users more confidence that the Developer ID-signed software you distribute has been checked by Apple for malicious components.
>
> If there are no issues, the notary service generates a ticket for you to staple to your software

The notarization will be required for binaries, frameworks, dylibs, apps in future macOS releases.

### In order to do this some steps are necessary:

- add `--timestamp` to **Other Code Signing Flags** in **Build Settings** for each target that produces a binary, framework, dylib or app
- add `--options=runtime` to **Other Code Signing Flags** (for Xcode < 10.2) or **Enable Hardened Runtime** (for Xcode >= 10.2) in **Build Settings**
- code sign everything(dylibs, frameworks, binaries and .apps.)

### Next, notarization can be done as follows:

- include every file that need to be notarized into a **.zip** file(other supported formats: **.dmg**, **.pkg**)
- upload the supported format to apple notarization service: Ex: `xcrun altool --notarize-app -f <path_to_zip_dmg_or_pkg> --primary-bundle-id <bundle_identifier> -u <apple_id> -p @keychain:"Application Loader: <apple_id>"` ---> this returns an **UUID** which will also be sent on the the mail address for the provided `<apple_id>` after the notarization is done
- check status and error logs(if any) with `xcrun altool --notarization-info <UUID_from_previous_step> -u <apple_id> -p @keychain:"Application Loader: <apple_id>"`
- the error logs can be downloaded with `curl LogFileURL`, where **LogFileURL** is returned in the **json response** of the previous command
- if everything is fine just staple the notarization using the command `xcrun stapler staple -v <path_to_app_dmg_or_pkg>`; only **app**, **dmg** and **pkg** can be stapled.

### Other useful commands:

- use `codesign -dvvv <path_to_file>` to check if codesigning is done, also check the timestamp value
- use `spctl -a -v <path_to_file>` to check if stapling is valid

Comment: Have you tried this with dylibs, etc. not organized as a Framework bundle? I am able to go through all the steps but Gatekeeper still rejects my ZIP on a fresh machine (in a VM).

Comment: I have a zip that contain some binaries, dylibs, scripts, makefiles. I have converted that into pkg. Now what I am suppose to do to notarize this pkg? Also, postinstall run launchd command so that PATH var is set without the need of relogin.